# why does setting `this.property` in a function in a class make a new property but getting `this.property` uses the class property?

Tags: javascript, oop, object

I have a class in javascript with a property (`is_initialized`) and a function (`isInitialized`).

**Class definition :**

```
function Test()
{
    this.is_initialized = { obj: { isInitialized: 'notyet' } };
    this.isInitialized = function( ref )
    {
        if ( !ref.obj )
        {
            console.log( 'now: ' + JSON.stringify( this.is_initialized ) );
/*line 9*/  this.is_initialized.obj.isInitialized = ref.isInitialized.toString();
            console.log( ref );
        }
        else {
            bluetoothle.isInitialized( this.isInitialized );
/*line 14*/ ref.obj = this.is_initialized.obj;
        }
    };
}
```

`bluetoothle.isInitialized` is a function in a cordova plugin (no knowledge of cordova is required for answering this question), it returns an object `{ isInitialized : true/false }` and will pass the first `if`-statement whilst my call to `isInitialized()` will execute the `else`.

**Question :**

Why does `this.is_initialized` on line 9 create a new property inside the function `isInitialized` while `this.is_initialized` on line 14 uses the property `is_initialized` in `Test()`?

Shouldn't it both use the property inside `Test()` or use a (new) variable inside `isInitialized()`?

And if it 'just' behaves like this, what can i do to deal with it?

**Code i ran :**

```
var t = new Test();
var r = {obj:{isInitialized:'nope'}};
t.isInitialized(r);

// console.log( 'now: ' + JSON.stringify( this.is_initialized ) ); on line 8:
// now: {"obj":{"isInitialized":"false"}}

// console.log( ref ); on line 10:
// Object {isInitialized: false}

console.log(JSON.stringify(r));
// {"obj":{"isInitialized":"notyet"}}

console.log(JSON.stringify(t));
// {"is_initialized":{"obj":{"isInitialized":"notyet"}}}
```

What just happened is this:

- i made a new instance of Test() and named it `t`.
- i made an object with matching structure of `is_initialized` in Test() but with a different value.
- i called the function with `r` as parameter.
- code in the `else` executes.
- asynchronous function with `isInitialized` as callback is called.
- the function created a reference between the existing `is_initialized` and `r`.
- the async function calls `isInitialized` and executes the code in the `if`.
- it logs the current value of `this.is_initialized` on line 8, somehow it gets `this.is_initialized` after line 9 is executed.
- line 9 executes, creating a new variable named `is_initialized` inside `isInitialized()` while i want it to set `is_initialized` in `Test()` and not create a new variable that dies when the function is done executing.
- it logs the object that was put into `this.is_initialized.obj.isInitialized`.
- i log r and see that it contains the initial value of `Test.is_initialized`.
- i log t and see that `is_initialized`'s value is still initial.

**Info :**

If you want to test it yourself to answer my question of the *why?* and the *how do i deal with it?* but need some code for `bluetoothle.isInitialized` just use this:

```
var bluetoothle = {isInitialized:function(){setTimeout(function(){func({isInitialized:false});},20);}};
// to execute:
bluetoothle.isInitialized(/*callbackfunction*/);
```

I would like to thank you for reading this long question.

Comment: What makes you think it would create a new "variable"?

Comment: @Bergi the console.log on line 8. it outputs a different value than `Test.is_initialized` and i can't find it anywhere after the function is done executing.

Comment: This seems to depend on the implementation of your `bluetoothle.isInitialized` function. If it is really asynchronous, as you say, then line 14 will be executed before line 9 of course.

Comment: @Bergi the assignment on line 14 is by reference, so it doesn't matter when it changes

Comment: When  you pass `this.isInitialized`, you're only passing the function, not the object. Therefore, when it invokes the function (inside the `setTimeout` callback in your test code), it doesn't know what the original object was, so it sets the value of `this` to the `window` object. As such, the async invocation is referencing the global object when it uses `this`. So this shouldn't work at all once you reach `this.is_initialized.obj.isInitialized = ` unless you defined a global variable called `is_initialized`.

Comment: Did you mean `bluetoothle.isInitialized( this.isInitialized.bind(this) );` and `var bluetoothle = {isInitialized:function(func) {…`? Otherwise your code doesn't execute without exceptions at all.

Comment: And by the way, there are no variables in your code except `t` and `r`. The rest are object properties. This makes your question harder to understand, not to mention having `is_initialized` and `isInitialized`.

Comment: @squint i am aware that it passes the function, `bluetoothle.isInitialized` requires a callback as parameter. Thanks for your comment, it is making more sense to me now,

Comment: @Bergi i haven't looked into using `bind(this)`, but i did forgot the add `func` as a parameter.

Comment: Yes, I wasn't telling you that you were passing a function. I was telling you that you're passing *only* the function and not the object. Glad to hear it's making sense.

Answer (score 0):

You're in a function.  Inside a function (unless it's declared as Test.prototype.isInitialized), the scoping rules for 'this' are different.  This is one of the gotchas that ES6 aims to eliminate.  (If you added "use strict"; at the top of the function most browsers would tell you this.)

Declare var self = this in Test and use self inside your interior function and you should get the result you want.  @squint has pretty much already said this.

Comment: "*Inside a function the scoping rules for 'this' are different*"??? The scoping rules for `this` are quite consistent. Different from what?

Comment: @user1329482 Bergi is right, the rules are the same, but when i passed the function ass callback it executed in the scope of `bluetoothle`, not `Test()`.
Using `bluetoothle.isInitialized( this.isInitialized.bind(this) );` (as Bergi said) fixed it for me.
@Bergi go ahead and make an answer to claim your rep and mark it for future visitors

Comment: @ThisNameBetterBeAvailable: I've already linked a canonical duplicate, no answer from me :-) If you still want me to get rep you're free to upvote on any of my other answers, but honestly I don't need it